# Is serial considered a keyword or a numeric type?

Tags: postgresql, conventions

[Here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) it is mentioned that, "the data types `smallserial`, `serial` and `bigserial` are not true types, but merely a notational convenience for creating unique identifier columns." Everywhere in the documentation they are all in lowercase except in this example

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    colname SERIAL
);
```

Usually, keywords are written in uppercase, but cannot find `serial` in the list of PostgreSQL keywords. So how should I write `SERIAL` or `serial`?

Comment: The use of `serial` [is discouraged](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial) to begin with.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that. How can I define an identity column? Cannot find in PostgreSQL docs.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html

Comment: Thanks. Couldn't imagine it can be a clause :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL is case-insensitive (unless from the edge case where you quote object names, but this isn't the case here), so from a functional perspective you can write `serial` or `SERIAL`, or even `Serial` or `sErIAL` if you particularly want to (but seriously - don't).

Now this becomes a question of style, so my recommendation would be to match styles and keep your scripts consistent. If you uppercase your `NUMERIC` and `VARCHAR` columns, use `SERIAL`, but if you have lowercase `numeric`s and `varchar`s, you should also have lowercase `serial`s.
Personally I prefer uppercasing them, but that's just me.

Note that identity columns are a better alternative these days [(`GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html)).